# Is it possible to use disable text selection script on everything exept input tag

Tags: javascript

I use **[this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/noselect.htm)** script in one of my applicatuions, but now I would like to do everything same way exept disapply this script for all `input` tags.

Could anyone say is it possible, ot there is some other solution?

Comment: Why are you using the script in the first place? In general it is not a good idea to change the default behaviour of the browser. Users are used to select text. Don't annoy them.

Comment: Don't spam. You either want to ask something relevant or answer. Everything else from my point of view is considered as spam.

Comment: Relevant from your point of view or from the ones who are trying to help you? If you are not open to advices, ok then. Good luck!

Comment: Okay. I took your advice into consideration. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only CSS, this should work in most modern browsers ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SvSZZ/1/)):

```
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

input {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -o-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is it. I will try in some other browsers, than FF4. If it is so. Then great thanks. Actually either way thanks.

Comment: Just a heads-up: I don't believe this will work in IE 8 or older.

Comment: That's okey. I need it not for the Front-end UI and mostly it should work in FF and Chrome and it does.